# How do I avoid including the headers of every class that needs to be BOOST serialised?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, include

I have the following situation (simplified):

a.h:

```
#include <boost/serialisation/serialisation.hpp>
class B;
using namespace std; using namespace boost;
class A {
   B *b;
   template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) { ar & b; }
};
```

b.h:

```
#include <boost/serialisation/serialisation.hpp>
class C;
using namespace std; using namespace boost;
class B {
   C *c;
   template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) { ar & c; }
};
```

c.h:

```
#include <boost/serialisation/serialisation.hpp>
using namespace std; using namespace boost;
class C {
   int somevar;
   template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) { ar & somevar; }
};
```

main.cxx:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
using namespace std; using namespace boost;

int main() {
   A a; // Create the object

   ofstream ofs("save");
   archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);

   oa << a; // Save the object

   return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is that I have to include the header files of all the classes that I want to serialise in the saving function (in this case right inside main). The problem with that is that there are a lot more than three classes, and they are much more complicated, resulting in a compilation bottleneck at this point.

I only recently begun using boost serialisation, but I've looked over the documentation and searched on both google and here, so I figure I've missed something obvious.

Does anybody have a solution for this such that only "a.h" needs to be included and not "b.h", "c.h", etc?

EDIT: This is hopefully the crucial part of the compilation error that occurs if I comment out the #include "b.h" and "c.h" lines:

```
main.cxx:17:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_abstract.hpp:72:4: error: incomplete type ‘B’ not allowed
```

Comment: btw - don't put `using namespace std;` and `using namespace boost;` in your header files - you can put it in 'cxx' files as you have, and then use the std:: qualifier as needed in the header file.

Comment: @quamrana: Thank you for your advice; but I just cobbled this example together off the top of my head to illustrate the problem I'm having. Any thoughts on that? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use explicit instantiation, and then define your serialize member functions in .cpp files. Then a.cpp can include b.h and c.h as needed, and users of a.h don't need to do that anymore.

Look into the pimpl-idiom examples http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/example/demo_pimpl_A.hpp (header) and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/example/demo_pimpl_A.cpp (source file) for how to do that.

Comment: The problem isn't linking, though; it's with compiling.

I'd post the output, but it's several hundred lines long.

I'll update the question with what I hope is the crucial error.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I understand now. I've just come down with a fever and am not thinking too well; sorry.

However, even if I do move the definitions of the serialise functions, doesn't that only move the error/bottleneck from main.o to a.o?

I experience the same error, but now it's in a.o, unless a.cxx #includes "b.h" and "c.h".

Comment: @Tim, `a.cpp` knows its dependencies. I.e it knows that it uses `b.h`. It will not have to include `c.h`, because class B does not anymore expose its dependencies by way of its serialization. So if `a.cpp` includes `b.h`, and `b.cpp` includes `c.h`, and you use explicit instantiation and define your serialization functions in your `.cpp` files, everything should go well, and every file only cares about its direct dependency. I've never used boost.serialization thought, but this sounds like it should work. Also consider @stijn's idea, which makes `main` just include `myserial.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I know nothing of boost serialisation.

Since you have template member functions `serialize` which have to have inline definitions, which are using the members, you should `#include` the header files for those members instead of just declaring eg `class B;`.

This will mean that main will only have to `#include "a.h"` in main and you shouldn't get compiler errors.

Comment: As I said to Johannes Schaub, that seems to simply move the bottleneck/error to a.o from main.o. I want to find a way (if there is one) of removing this bottleneck altogether.
 
Regardless, thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there is a method, *any* method, that needs to access A, B and C, there is simply no other way than to make A, B and C visible to that method, and in yur case tha means including all 3 header files. So the compiler bottlenck you talk about cannot be solved.

Second, you should be able to use non-invasive functions for Boost's serialization. Not sure if that solves your particular problem but it's definitely worth a try and it does move all serialization related stuff into one single header file.

```
  //header myserialization.h
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version, A& a) { ar & a.*b; }

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version, B& b) { ar & b.*c; }

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version, C& c) { ar & c.somevar; }
```